# How to display card 4 cards in a single row in Reactjs using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
const ViewCategory = () => {
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/products', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("List of customers", response.data);
            setData(response.data);
            setisLoaded(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}, []);

const [data, setData] = useState();
const [isloaded, setisLoaded] = useState(false);



let product = null;
if (isloaded) {
    product = data.map(product1 => ( <
        div className = "container" >
        <
        div className = "row" >
        <
        div className = "card" >
        <
        div class = "col-sm" >


        <
        div className = "card-body" >

        <
        h4 className = "card-title" > {
            product1.name
        } < /h4>

        <
        p className = "card-text" > {
            product1.brand
        }. < /p> <
        button className = "btn btn-primary" > View < /button> <
        /div> <
        /div>

        <
        /div> <
        /div> <
        /div>
    ))
}

return ( <
    div > {
        product
    } < /div>
);
```

}

export default ViewCategory;

**I am trying to display 4 cards in a single row that I am displaying using map method. Initaly I am getting one card in one row.How can I display multiple cards in a single row what is the best possible method can anyone suggest me**

Comment: [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/) from bootstrap should work for you

Answer (score 0):

To get the cards displayed in a single row, rendering logic needs to be changed to:

```
let products = null;

if (isloaded) {
    products = data.map((product) => (
        <div className="card">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h4 className="card-title"> {product.name} </h4>
                    <p className="card-text"> {product.brand}. </p>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary"> View </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));
}

return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">{products}</div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you share me some link where I can have a look at rendering logic?

Comment: Please take a look at the included code sample in my answer that already fixes the rendering to meet your needs.